# Heroku help rails migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have tried to deploy on heroku with git. Git console:

```
  Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
    $ heroku rake db:migrate
    rake aborted!
    /app/x/home/lib/tasks/statistik.rake:19: synt
    ax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
              @existing = Reklamer.where(dato: '@stats[0]').first
                                              ^
    /app/x/home/lib/tasks/statistik.rake:19: synt
    ax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
              @existing = Reklamer.where(dato: '@stats[0]').first
                                                           ^
    /app/x/home/Rakefile:7
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    (in /app/x/home)

    Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
    $ heroku db:push
    Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
```

I am using mysql in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have a syntax error in your finder.

```
Reklamer.where(dato: '@stats[0]')
```

should be

```
Reklamer.where(dato => @stats[0])
```

Secondly `heroku db:push` is failing as you haven't installed the taps gem yet

```
Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
```

To do this run:

```
gem install taps
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing taps did not fix it for me, but this did:

```
sudo gem upgrade heroku
```